# It is possible to force user to open link by safari when user are using chrome in ios

Tags: javascript

I build the javascript WebRTC website. IOS chrome can't support WebRTC but safari can.
In IOS system, how to force Chrome users to use Safari to open new links?

Appreciate your help

Comment: I would say, you can't make a client system use a particular browser - just inform the user to use sufferi if they are using chrome

Comment: My opinion DONT DO THIS. This is such a bad UX that users probably stop using your site, service or whatever. Simply build a route that informs a user.